# {BATCH} Random Not Working?

Tags: batch-file

***UPDATE***

Solution Found, working code:

```
@echo off
color f0
title Date Of Birth Generator

:begin

    REM Setting Current Year (Year Cannot Surpass Current Year)
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %%g in ('echo %date%') do (
        set cYear=%%g
    )   

        REM Year
        set /a year=(%RANDOM% %% %cYear%) + 1

            REM Leap Year Check
            set /a mod=%year% %% 4
            if %mod%==0 (
                set jy=1
            ) else (
                set jy=0
            )



    REM Month
    set /a month=(%RANDOM% %% 12) + 1

        REM Define The Maximum Days In Random Month
        if %month%==1 set dm=31
        if %month%==3 set dm=31
        if %month%==5 set dm=31
        if %month%==7 set dm=31
        if %month%==8 set dm=31
        if %month%==10 set dm=31
        if %month%==12 set dm=31

            REM February
            if %month%==2 if %jy%==1 (
                set dm=29
            ) else (
                set dm=28
            )
            set dm=30
            if %month% LSS 10 set month=0%month%

    REM Day
    set /a day=(%RANDOM% %% %dm%) + 1
    if %day% LSS 10 set day=0%day%

    REM Compile Date
    cls
    echo Format: DD/MM/YYYY
    set cDate=%day%/%month%/%year%
    echo %cDate%
    pause>nul
    goto begin
```

***Old Post (original question, original code***

> This code is supposed to generate a random date taking into
>   consideration the amount of days in a month and if it is a leap year.
>   The problem is, the %random% variable does not seem to be working?
>   When I generate a random month, it always generates 02 on my desktop
>   and 06 on my laptop... I've tried disabling parts of the code and even
>   redesigning the random month generation process. Any ideas would be
>   greatly appreciated!
>
> ```
> @echo off
> color f0
> title Date Of Birth Generator
> :begin
> for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %%g in ('echo %date%') do (
> set cyear=%%g
> )
> set /a mod=%cyear% %% 4
> if %mod%==0 (
> set jy=1
> ) else (
> set jy=0
> )
>
> set /a mon=%RANDOM% * (12 - 1 + 1) / 32768 + 1
> if %mon%==1 set dm=31
> if %mon%==3 set dm=31
> if %mon%==5 set dm=31
> if %mon%==7 set dm=31
> if %mon%==8 set dm=31
> if %mon%==10 set dm=31
> if %mon%==12 set dm=31
> if %mon%==2 if %jy%==1 (
> set dm=29
> ) else (
> set dm=28
> )
> if %mon% LSS 10 set mon=0%mon%
> echo %mon%
> pause
>
> set /a d=%RANDOM% * (%dm% - 1 + 1) / 32768 + 1
> ```

Comment: You are never presetting the `dm` variable...

Comment: You could shorten you script by a lot of lines if you used the code I provided to get the last day of the month.

Comment: Instead of including the solution in your question, you should post an answer...

Comment: The variable dm will always be 30.

Comment: @Squashman Yea, I noticed that and fixed it in my code, Thanks for telling me though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the Modulus is much better in your scenario:

```
set /a mon=%RANDOM% %% 12 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax instead to get your random

```
set /a mon=%RANDOM% %% 12 + 1
```

Here is a function to get you the last day of a month when you CALL it with the the year and month.

```
:DaysOfMonth Year Month
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set /a "yy = %~1, mm = 100%~2 %% 100"
set /a "n = 30 + !(((mm & 9) + 6) %% 7) + !(mm ^ 2) * (!(yy %% 4) - !(yy %% 100) + !(yy %% 400) - 2)"
endlocal &set day=%n%
GOTO :EOF
```

Then you can use the variable day to get your random day of the month.

```
set /a d=%RANDOM% %% %day% + 1
```